# How do I find a date within a column

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, finance

df1

```
  Name, Date, Amount, Q1 Date
  Mike, 1/31/2020, 1000, 3/31/2020
  Tom, 2/28/2020, 2000, 3/31/2020
  Sandra, 3/31/2020, 3000, 3/31/2020
  Julie, 3/31/2020, 4000, 3/31/2020
```

My code for calculation field

```
if df1.at[df1.index[-1],'Q1 Date'].isin(df1['Date'])(axis=1) :
            df1['Calc'] = (df1['Amount']*.25)
```

result should be:

```
  Name, Date, Amount, Q1 Date, Calc

  Mike, 1/31/2020, 1000, 3/31/2020, 
  Tom, 2/28/2020, 2000, 3/31/2020,
  Sandra, 3/31/2020, 3000, 3/31/2020, 750
  Julie, 3/31/2020, 4000, 3/31/20, 1000
```

the error i'm getting is AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'isin'

Comment: could you clarify: you want to check if the entry in 'Date' column equals the entry in column 'Q1 Date' and if so, multiply 'Amount' by .25 ?

Comment: Yes that's it. I probably over complicated it!

Comment: It'll be good if you consider accepting or upvoting an answer to reward those who helped you, or if there is something wrong you could leave a comment too ;) @Hedge_hog

Answer (score 1):

```
In [136]: df = pd.read_csv("a.csv")

In [137]: df
Out[137]:
     Name       Date  Amount    Q1 Date
0    Mike  1/31/2020    1000  3/31/2020
1     Tom  2/28/2020    2000  3/31/2020
2  Sandra  3/31/2020    3000  3/31/2020
3   Julie  3/31/2020    4000  3/31/2020

In [138]: df["Calc"] = df[df["Q1 Date"] == df["Date"]]["Amount"] * .25

In [139]: df
Out[139]:
     Name       Date  Amount    Q1 Date    Calc
0    Mike  1/31/2020    1000  3/31/2020     NaN
1     Tom  2/28/2020    2000  3/31/2020     NaN
2  Sandra  3/31/2020    3000  3/31/2020   750.0
3   Julie  3/31/2020    4000  3/31/2020  1000.0
```

Comment: see the comment below OP's post; is that really what he needs?

Comment: @MrFuppes Updated my answer. I didn't read the comment section

Answer (score 1):

You could try with `numpy.where`:

```
df['Calc']=np.where(df['Date']==df['Q1 Date'],df.Amount*.25,'')
```

Output:

```
df
     Name       Date  Amount    Q1 Date    Calc
0    Mike 2020-01-31    1000 2020-03-31        
1     Tom 2020-02-28    2000 2020-03-31        
2  Sandra 2020-03-31    3000 2020-03-31   750.0
3   Julie 2020-03-31    4000 2020-03-31  1000.0
```

Comment: Why bother with defining a separate variable for the boolean mask and why the empty string? Why not simply `np.where((df['Date']==df['Q1 Date']), df['Amount']*.25, np.nan)`? ;-)

Comment: The empty string was because of the desired output OP posted. About the mask, it was pure habit when using large masks nested, but you're right, in this case it will be cleaner to put the mask inside. I will change it, thanks for the advice :) @MrFuppes

Answer (score 1):

I think this gives you what you want:

```
df1.Date = pd.to_datetime(df1.Date, format='%d/%M/%Y')
df1['Q1 Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Q1 Date'], format='%d/%M/%Y')
df1['Calc'] = df1['Amount']*0.25*(df1['Date'] == df1['Q1 Date'])

print(df1):
 Name                Date  Amount             Q1 Date    Calc
 0    Mike 2020-01-01 00:31:00    1000 2020-01-03 00:31:00     0.0
 1     Tom 2020-01-02 00:28:00    2000 2020-01-03 00:31:00     0.0
 2  Sandra 2020-01-03 00:31:00    3000 2020-01-03 00:31:00   750.0
 3   Julie 2020-01-03 00:31:00    4000 2020-01-03 00:31:00  1000.0
```

Comment: I think string comparison should do fine, no need to cast to datetime. If the OP can live with the `0.0`, this is nice and clean.